# How to get the value from a listview?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Currently I have this:

```
$('#restaurants').append('<li><a rel="external" href="details.html?id=' + row.id + '"><h2>' + row.name + '</h2><span class="ui-li-count">' + row.rating / 10 + '</span><p>' + row.category + '</p></a><a href="#delete" value="' + row.id '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a></li>');
```

As you can see it will call a popup.

```
        <div data-role="popup" id="delete" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
            <h3>Restaurant Verwijderen</h3>
            <p>Weet u zeker dat u dit restaurant uit uw favorieten wilt verwijderen?</p>
            <a href="#" id="remove" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Ja</a>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Nee</a>
        </div>
```

Now I want to click on the button "Ja", and get the value what I set before.

```
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        // Option one
        console.log($("#delete").attr('value'));

        // Option two
        console.log($("#delete").val());
});
```

As result, I get an "undefined" message in the console. It looks very strange, because if I just watch the HTML version, I see that the value has been set to the ID that I need.

```
<a href="#delete" value="4032" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a"></a>
```

Comment: cant find id  #delete in your HTML ?

Comment: can you please create fiddle example?

Comment: I can't make it work, because the $('#restaurants').append is an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to access the value of id. I hope it will work.

```js
$('#deleteID').click(function()
   {
     id = $(this).attr('value');
     $('#remove').attr('data-id',id);
   });
```

Then when clicking on remove you can access the id like

```js
$('#remove').click(function(){       
        console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));       
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to anchor tag like

```html
<a id="deleteID" href="#delete" value="4032" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a"></a>
```

and then access the value of anchor by using id "deleteID" like

```html
console.log($("#deleteID").attr('value'));
```

Comment: @jamie Are you able to alert other attributes of anchor tag like data-rel,data-position-to etc.??

Comment: I am able to alert them (tried data-num), but also the same problem... all undefined.

Comment: @Jamie It should work according to above given solution. I have tested it. Make sure you have added the id attribute "#deleteID" while appending your html. Otherwise please post your code so that I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/

Scroll down to "Split Buttons" and you can see the source.

When I add the value attribute hard coded to the `<ul>` in the HTML then I will receive the value, and if I try to set the value by the `row.id` in the append, then it's not working.

As you can see in the link, the listview has a `data-split-theme`, with a button. After clicking on the button, I want to receive the id (the value). But I don't know where I need to add the value attribute in the append...